# know about web app to monitor server activity?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, linode, rackspace

I have running some servers on rackspace and I want to know if there is a web application like linode-graphs as you can see in the image ?

I want to see graphs of server activities like:

1. ram
2. cpu
3. network
4. io
5. ...etc

thanks for your help :)

[image: linode graphs]

Answer (score 4):

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is just what you are asking for. It consists of two parts; `munin-master` and `munin-node`. If you just have one host you can install both packages and munin will collect a set of default statistics, draw graphs and create a simple HTML dashboard for you. If you have several machines you want to monitor you only need one `munin-master`, but you will need `munin-node` on all hosts you want to gather statistics from.

### About munin

> Munin is a networked resource monitoring tool that can help analyze
>   resource trends and "what just happened to kill our performance?"
>   problems. It is designed to be very plug and play. A default
>   installation provides a lot of graphs with almost no work.

### Installing munin

#### Ubuntu / Debian

```
apt-get install munin munin-node
```

#### RHEL / CentOS

```
yum install munin.noarch munin-node.noarch
```

Answer (score 1):

Munin is definitely an opinion. Another solution that i like is Observium. Take a look at [Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) here. You will get everything you need including the same graphing engine (rrdtool) in this case. I find the interface pretty easy to navigate. The only catch is you can only grab it via SVN and there are some dependencies that you'll need to address.